# Symfony multiple entity managers/connnections issue

Tags: symfony, symfony5

I have two symfony installations. One is a website and serves to store the users, sessions, account info, etc. The latter is an customer specific application install, with their own distinct DB and tables.

Authentication works fine on the main site. The idea being I could authenticate SSO and redirect the user back to their app instance.

I have managed to replicate my auth configuration in the application instances (mostly) how the application instances have slightly different doctrine config:

```
# config/packages/doctrine.yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                # configure these for your database server
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
            account:
                # Sessions and users are stored here
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL_SITE)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Core'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: App
            account:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                connection: account
                mappings:
                    Sso:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Shared'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Shared'
                        alias: Sso
```

This works - kinda - until Symfony tries to authenticate. The user entity is being retreived from the application DB, which does not have the `Users` table.

I thought the above ORM configuration made this obvious? All other scripts (schema:create, etc) seem to work...what am I missing?!?

EDIT **security.yaml**

```
security:
    #enable_authenticator_manager: true

    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Shared\User
                property: email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider

            #custom_authenticators:
            #    - App\Security\SessionAuthenticator

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        #- { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_USER }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: So the user entity is under Entity/Shared/User?  You don't have a Entity/Core/User?  The reason I ask is that the Symfony multiple entity manager implementation is basically broke if the User entity is mapped in both managers.  Consider updating your question with the relevant results from running "bin/console doctrine:mapping:info --em=default" and "--em=account"

Comment: That is correct. The em="account" currently has a single entity "User" and a sessions table (not mapped to any entities). The em="default" has 3 entities Task, Label, Log. I tried changing their prefix accordingly (App\Entity\Core && App\Entity\Shared) but am getting this error now The class `App\Entity\Shared\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity\Core`

Comment: So doctrine:mapping:info gives the expected results?  I am assuming your main site only has the default entity manager?  Maybe you could show the user provider section of your app's security.yaml.  It seems like it is using the default entity manager instead of the account entity manager.

Comment: To me it seems that is exactly whats happening, not sure why? I'll update main post with security.yaml from 'app'

Comment: It's been awhile but I'm pretty sure the default user provider always uses the first entity manager defined.  You could actually try swapping the order in which the managers are defined in doctrine.yaml and see what happens.  But even if it works that just masks the underlying problem.  I think you might need to define a custom user provider and explicitly configure it's service to use the account entity manager.

Comment: Is all of this even necessary? Could I not just implement a custom authenticator (https://wouterj.nl/2020/04/authenticators-new-symfony-security) and grab the user details from the SESSION? If I ever need to query the "users" table from within the "app" I can explicitly specify the "em" or connection, I think? This just seems like over-kill...but wrapping my head around the security architecture has left me wanting the easiest solution :)

Comment: By all means use the new authenticator.  Once you have it configured then it should all work fine.

Comment: So that would work and allow me to *not* have to re-introduce/keep identical copies of User entities in my "app" instances? Literally just add an "authenticator" which knows how to grab user details from session and return a valid User object? Do I understand the gist of it?

Comment: No.  The session only stores some user info.  Pretty sure you always need to be able to refresh the user from the database.  I suppose you could try it.  I think we are going a bit astray though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226606/discussion-between-alex-barylski-and-cerad).